# Extracting #define statements from another .c file to retain reverse-compatibility

Tags: c

I find myself with a "face-palm" type issue, and need advice to solve it

I am working on rolling out a new embedded C project that has been built around a logic engine that was originally written in Dynamic C (DC). The logic engine is written entirely in 1 file, there is no header file. The crux of my problem is that the senior developer wants this logic engine to compile In DC AND in the new C project so that only one copy of the logic, defines, etc needs to be maintained. One of the properties of DC is the includes files are very complicated for many reasons that I don't want to get into here. Long story short, extracting the variables, structure definitions, and define statements to a .h file compromises the DC project, it will not compile. Below is a summary of the two files of interest:

---

Dynamic C (DC) logic engine, 'DClogicEngine.c'
.#include 'newProject.h'
~ 1000 lines of structs and variables needed in new project.
~ 1500 #define statements needed in new C project
~ 20k lines of logic

---

New Project (C code) 'newProject.c'
~some code.
~dozens of neccesary references to the #define statements in 'DClogicEngine.c'

---

To re-iterate my problem, I am perfectly able to use #ifdefs and other compiler options to tie into the logic, and because this is a program I have control over, I was able to include a .h file, allowing me to include the necessary logic in the DC file. The problem is accessing the thousands of #define statements in 'DClogicEngine.c' from 'newProject.c'.

The issue I have is the notorious, face-palm, and age-old problem of "I want to include a .c file in another." I've tried countless ways of placing #include xx.c in different places and then getting clever with include guards, but no luck (and no surprises). I found an old thread and thought I might share the answer because it is humorous:
[image: An Old Post on the classic issue]

The bottom line is extracting these statements to a .h file will cause a great deal of pain in retaining reverse compatibility with the DC build. Perhaps a burden that will have to be beared?

No doubt I have myself a stupid problem. My question in three parts is:
1.) has anybody encountered a problem like this and how did you solve it?
2.) Is there anything creative I can do to make this work? Does anybody know any compiler wizardry that may help?
2.) general advice, what is the least painful way to solve this?

Comment: Can you do it the other way - generate the DC source from the C source at build time? That is, make the C code all nicely structured with headers, etc and then at compile time use a build script or makefle rule to generate the DC source?

Comment: Put the *code* (but not the header-like parts) of the monolith DC file inside an `#ifndef INCLUDED_FROM_C` block. Then in your code `#define INCLUDED_FROM_C` before `#include <DCLogicEngine.c>`. This *will* require some  changes in the DC file, though minimal ones.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", just for fun. In contrary to many other new members, your question is well written, and perhaps misses just one thing: a [example]. I don't know anything about DC, could you provide a URL?

Comment: It looks like you can #include the C file, but you are worried this is bad programming practice? Is that the summary of the problem you want to solve? Or, do you have question regarding _how_ to include the DC .C file?

Comment: Do you need to compile/build/use the newProject.c file in the DC environment? What kind of build environment are you using? (makefile, cmake, some IDE, ...)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the DC file does still change (being regenerated maybe) and that if it does change,  both builds (in DC environment and in the new environment) should notice and rebuild accordingly?

Comment: Making a MRE would be helpful. For that you'd have to "invent" a small version of the DC file, just to get the idea across. Make something which has the same problems and structure but obviously does not contain thousands of lines.

Answer (score 0):

> Long story short, extracting the variables, structure definitions, and define statements to a .h file compromises the DC project, it will not compile.

This cannot be. You are saying that you have *a single DC source file.* There should be no systemic reason why you wouldn't be able to extract the part of that source file which contains structure definitions and other declarations in a header file which can be used by both the DC implementation and the the C re-implementation. (I don't know DC; it's possible that there are incompatibilities with **C**, but the refactoring should not affect the DC side — the compiler still sees a single translation unit like before. That it now consists of a source file with an included header is irrelevant to the compiler.)

The problems your were encountering were likely not of a general nature. They were likely specific to the project and circumstances (order of declarations etc.). Try to isolate them and post specific problems here.

Comment: @dxiv Well, the OP had an include directive in their DC example! And p. 227 in the [documentation](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/019-0167_L.pdf) lists it. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, objection withdrawn. Turns out my quick search had found a book from 2005 for some reason.

Comment: I solved the issue, in the end you were correct. If you are interested you can see a simple example of the steps one needs to take inorder to format a DC header file:https://catherineh.github.io/programming/2016/03/31/libraries-in-dynamic-c.                            As you can imagine, things get quite complicated as the header file grows. And the errors generated by the DC compiler do not even point the .h file that introduced the error into the compile! It is Evil.

Comment: Glad it worked out. You can upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for your responses,

In the end, the only way I could make this thing budge was by extracting the necessary variables, structs, and define statements from DClogicEngine.c to a new DClogicEngine.h. We were hesitant to do this simple step because we have failed to make this work in the past and wasted a great deal of time and effort in the process.

We started by extracting a few things a mutual 'dummy.h' the file that was shared between the projects. After we saw that we could appease errors on both the original DC compiler and the C compiler we moved everything to mutual .h file. Eventually, we hit a point where it became apparent we needed to include function prototypes in the header as well, just as we had done the first time (we thought this could be avoided but in the end, it had to be done).

What we did differently this time to appease the DC compiler was placing #ifndef DC_BUILD statements around the function prototypes in the .h file. Simple and effective!

If anyone has this problem in the future these are the steps that we used to solve this problem:

1.) The DC compiler openly accepts define statements, variables, and struct definitions if you remember to use the appropriate startHeader and endHeader tags detailed here, In our case, this was completely painless:
https://catherineh.github.io/programming/2016/03/31/libraries-in-dynamic-c

2.) Avoid the addition of any function prototypes in the .h file, the DC compiler absolutely hates them (unless you have a solid understanding of DC)! Make use of #ifdefs to hide ALL function prototypes in the .h file from the DC compiler.